# Windows XP SP3 on Macbook Has Limited Disk Space

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, macbook, boot-camp

I setup Windows XP SP3 on a 40 GB partition using bootcamp (partition formatted for NTFS).  For some reason, the hard drive properties only show ~3 GB of space available.  Funny thing is though, I've hardly installed anything on the system...

and if I open the windows explorer, select all directories, and check properties, it appears that I'm only using 11 GB of space.

What gives? I thought there might be hidden files/folders so I enabled the option to show it but still nada.  Has anyone come across this before?  Any suggestions for how to proceed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ran a chkdsk /f on the windows partition and it found some errors that supposedly was causing problems.  After the reboot, it appears to be working now and acknowledging the full amount of space.

Not sure how or why this occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try updating your Boot Camp drivers, although I'm not sure it will help (but shouldn't hurt).

32bit: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL996
64bit: DL979

Comment: Thanks. Upgraded didn't resolve the issue but it was a good idea and fixed some other quirky behavior.